# Examples of taskflow in Oracle ADF that depicts navigation rules and other actvities. What is unbounded and a bounded task flow?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am familiar with JSF. And I have to do some project work on Oracle ADF which is a similar technology as JSF. I am going thru some questions(http://myexpwithoracleadf.blogspot.in/2013/04/oracle-adf-task-flow-interview.html) on Oracle ADF and trying to figure out the similarities between these(ADF and JSF) so that I get a fair idea about Oracle ADF. I have came across something called as taskflow. And further classified as unbounded and bounded taskflows.

1. My Idea is that task flows resemble navigation rules-it is used not only for navigation between pages but also some other activities, what are those other activities?.
2. And can somebody further explain me unbounded and bounded taskflow with examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF task flows provide a modular approach for defining control flow in a Fusion web application. Instead of representing an application as a single large JSF page flow, you can break it up into a collection of reusable task flows. Each task flow contains a portion of the application's navigational graph. The nodes in the task flows are activities. An activity node represents a simple logical operation such as displaying a page, executing application logic, or calling another task flow. The transitions between the activities are called control flow cases.

Bounded task flow: A specialized form of task flow that, in contrast to the unbounded task flow, has a single entry point (an entry point is a view activity that can be directly requested by a browser) and zero or more exit points. It contains its own set of private control flow rules, activities, and managed beans. A bounded task flow allows reuse, parameters, transaction management, reentry, and can render within an ADF region in a JSF page.

Task flows provide a more modular and transaction- aware approach to navigation and application control. Like standard JSF navigation flows, task flows contain mostly viewable pages (or page fragments). Aside from navigation, task flows can also have nonvisual activities that can be chained together to affect the page flow and application behavior. For example, these nonvisual activities can call methods on managed beans, evaluate an EL expression and choose navigation direction using a router, or call another task flow. This facilitates reuse, as business logic can be invoked independently of the page being displayed.

I suggest you watch these two short videos for more detail, [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/taskflow-overview-p1/taskflow-overview-p1.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/taskflow-overview-p2/taskflow-overview-p2.html) and look at the docs, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/develop/GUID-FF3ABDAA-D44B-4487-9CC8-5D41186AB4F3.htm#ADFFD20573).